# CV2 SeamlessClone (-215:Assertion Failed)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a neural network that outputs segments of a face - I'm working on a function that combines these segments together and then clones them into a real face.

Example images are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLeOd.jpg, I do not have the reputation to include them inline.

So far my function takes the makeup face and lips segment and combines them with addition. The left and right eyes are then cloned in with seamlessClone (the right eye is flipped first). 
Then the combined makeup segments are cloned into the normal face.

Very occasionally, my combination function fails and returns a (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function 'cv::Mat::Mat' error.

My function is below, I have only seen it error at the last seamlessClone

```
def combineFace(images, radius = 70):
    # Given image segments and eye radii, combine face.
    realFace    = tensor2im(images['realNormal'])
    makeupFace  = tensor2im(images['fakeMakeupFace'])
    makeupLeft  = tensor2im(images['fakeMakeupLeft'])
    makeupRight = tensor2im(images['fakeMakeupRight'])
    makeupLips  = tensor2im(images['fakeMakeupLips'])
    makeupRight = cv2.flip(makeupRight, 1)
    # I use cv2 and dlib to get face landmarks and interesting points.
    normalLandmarks = faceLandmarks(realFace)
    facePoints      = getFacePoints(normalLandmarks)
    # PP means pupil points
    outerPoints, leftPP, rightPP, lipPoints, eyeMids = facePoints
    # eyeMid is (x, y) of center of eye obtained from landmark points
    leftEye  = eyeMids[0]
    rightEye = eyeMids[1]

    faceMask = np.zeros(realFace.shape, realFace.dtype)
    cv2.fillPoly(faceMask, [outerPoints], [255, 255, 255])
    cv2.fillPoly(faceMask, [lipPoints], [0, 0, 0])
    cv2.fillPoly(faceMask, [leftPP], [0, 0, 0])
    cv2.fillPoly(faceMask, [rightPP], [0, 0, 0])


    # Occasionally, the eye segments overlap eachother so I cut the right eye from the left and vice 
    # versa

    leftMask = np.zeros(realFace.shape, realFace.dtype)
    cv2.circle(leftMask, leftEye, radius, [255, 255, 255], -1)
    cv2.circle(leftMask, rightEye, radius,  [0, 0, 0], -1)
    # Errors if i do not use UMat
    cv2.circle(cv2.UMat(makeupLeft), rightEye, radius, [0, 0, 0], -1)

    rightMask = np.zeros(realFace.shape, realFace.dtype)
    cv2.circle(rightMask, rightEye, radius, [255, 255, 255], -1)
    cv2.circle(rightMask, leftEye, radius,  [0, 0, 0], -1)
    cv2.circle(cv2.UMat(makeupRight), leftEye, radius, [0, 0, 0], -1)

    # Combine face output and lips
    baseCombine = makeupFace + makeupLips
    # Left Eye
    output = cv2.seamlessClone(makeupLeft,  baseCombine, leftMask, leftEye, cv2.MIXED_CLONE)
    output = cv2.seamlessClone(makeupRight, output, rightMask, rightEye, cv2.MIXED_CLONE)


    # Get center of face
    faceRect = cv2.boundingRect(outerPoints)
    x, y, w, h = faceRect

    output = cv2.bitwise_and(output, faceMask)
    center = ( x + w // 2, y + h // 2)

    # I have only seen the function error at this point 
    combinedFace = cv2.seamlessClone(output, realFace, faceMask, center, cv2.MIXED_CLONE)
    return combinedFace
```

Any idea why this is occasionally erroring?

All input images have the form (256, 256, 3)

Comment: The error has something to do with the face center calculation. If I use a while square as a mask, and the center of the dest image and the cloning center,
the function works fine. 

I know the cv2 error means that something is overflowing something else, but I'm not very familiar with cv2 so I don't know what is overflowing what.
I have edited the code so that the face and faceMask is cropped out of the 256x256 image based on the faceRect, I am then checking if placing the cropped
face overflows the destination image and adjusting the center coords if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of the function works much better. There was something wrong with my face center calculation which was causing the error

```
def combineFace(images, radius = 70):
    # Given image segments and eye radii, combine face.
    realFace    = tensor2im(images['realNormal'])
    makeupFace  = tensor2im(images['fakeMakeupFace'])
    makeupLeft  = tensor2im(images['fakeMakeupLeft'])
    makeupRight = tensor2im(images['fakeMakeupRight'])
    makeupLips  = tensor2im(images['fakeMakeupLips'])

    # Right eye is flipped before input into the network.
    makeupRight = cv2.flip(makeupRight, 1)

    normalLandmarks = faceLandmarks(realFace)
    facePoints      = getFacePoints(normalLandmarks)

    outerPoints, leftPP, rightPP, lipPoints, eyeMids = facePoints
    leftEye  = eyeMids[0]
    rightEye = eyeMids[1]


    leftMask = np.zeros(makeupLeft.shape, makeupLeft.dtype)
    cv2.circle(leftMask, leftEye, radius,   [255, 255, 255], -1)
    cv2.circle(leftMask, rightEye, radius,  [0, 0, 0], -1)
    # Errors if i do not use cv2.UMat
    cv2.circle(cv2.UMat(makeupLeft), rightEye, radius, [0, 0, 0], -1)

    rightMask = np.zeros(makeupRight.shape, makeupRight.dtype)
    cv2.circle(rightMask, rightEye, radius, [255, 255, 255], -1)
    cv2.circle(rightMask, leftEye, radius,  [0, 0, 0], -1)
    cv2.circle(cv2.UMat(makeupRight), leftEye, radius, [0, 0, 0], -1)

    # Base output is combination of face without lips and pupils + lips
    baseCombine = makeupFace + makeupLips
    # Areas around eyes are changes
    output = cv2.seamlessClone(makeupLeft,  baseCombine, leftMask,  leftEye, cv2.MIXED_CLONE)
    output = cv2.seamlessClone(makeupRight, output,      rightMask, rightEye, cv2.MIXED_CLONE)

    # Find center of face 
    faceRect   = cv2.boundingRect(outerPoints)

    x, y, w, h = faceRect 

    if x < 0:
        x = 0
    if y < 0: 
        y = 0

    faceCenter = ( x + w // 2, y + h // 2)

    croppedOutput = output[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    faceMask = np.zeros(realFace.shape, realFace.dtype)
    cv2.fillPoly(faceMask, [outerPoints], [255, 255, 255])
    cv2.fillPoly(faceMask, [lipPoints],   [0, 0, 0])
    cv2.fillPoly(faceMask, [leftPP],      [0, 0, 0])
    cv2.fillPoly(faceMask, [rightPP],     [0, 0, 0])

    croppedMask = faceMask[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    if len(croppedOutput) == 0:
        print("OUTPUT 0")
        print("FACE RECT: ", faceRect)


    sourceW, sourceH, sCH = realFace.shape
    width, height, ch = croppedOutput.shape

    faceWidth  = width/2
    faceHeight = height/2
    xdiff = 0
    ydiff = 0
    cx = faceCenter[0]
    cy = faceCenter[1]

    if cx - faceWidth < 0:
        # Face overflows left
        xdiff = abs(cx - faceWidth)
    if cx + faceWidth > sourceW:
        xdiff = (cx + faceWidth - sourceW) * -1

    if cy + faceHeight > sourceH:
        ydiff = (cy + faceHeight - sourceH) * -1
    if cy - faceHeight < 0:
        ydiff = abs(cy - faceHeight)

    centerx = int(cx + xdiff)
    centery = int(cy + ydiff)
    center = (centerx, centery)

    # We move center, also move mask?


    combinedFace = cv2.seamlessClone(croppedOutput, realFace, croppedMask, center, cv2.MIXED_CLONE)
    return combinedFace
```